# How to convert a double byte utf-8 character to utf-16 in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got the following double byte utf8 character

```
\ud83d\ude04
```

(It's an ios emoji).
I want to convert to a utf-16

```
U+1F604
```

How do I do this?
I've tried the following:

```
$utf8_string = "\ud83d\ude04";
$utf16_string = mb_convert_encoding($utf8_string, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
```

But I get the original utf8 string.  It doesnt get converted.

I'm thinking I may need to decode the utf8 string first.  I've tried doing this with json_decode (which works quite nicely to decode utf8 character sets).  But still no joy.

Comment: `\u...` is not UTF-8 and `U+...` is not UTF-16. The former looks like a JSON encoded representation of the character and the latter looks like a formal Unicode code point. Neither is a UTF encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's get the terms right:

- `\ud83d\ude04` is a Unicode escape sequence as used in, for example, Javascript. It is not "UTF-8".
- It is also not "double byte", but rather a surrogate pair.
- U+1F604 is the official notation of a Unicode code point. It is not "UTF-16".

The first step is to get from "\ud83d\ude04" to a UTF-8 encoded string. The easiest method is:

```
$utf8 = json_decode('"\ud83d\ude04"'); // note the added "" quotes
```

To convert from here to a UTF-16 encoded string, simply do:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $utf8)
```

However the result is not "U+1F604", but rather a UTF-16 encoded string (the hex representation of which is `feffd83dde04`).

To get a Unicode code point notation, the easiest way is probably to convert to UCS-4 and adjust leading zeros:

```
$ucs4      = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $utf8);
$codepoint = sprintf('U+%04s', ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($ucs4)), '0'));
```